# Position 2 blocks side by side filling the view port with one block set to width:Auto

Tags: css, css-float

Lots of discussion here on this topic, but still can't get what I want. I have 2 div blocks that I want to put side by side.

The left most side contains a tree menu and a background color. I have the width set to auto and want the background color to fill the view port vertically regardless of how many nodes are in the tree menu.

I want the contents of the right block to be next to the left block with a 2px margin and have an auto Height and Width that fills the remaing space and gets scroll bars for any overflow.

The only way I have found to get the left block to fill the view port vertically is setting postion:absolute and top: 0px, bottom: 0px. But when I do that I cannot figure out how to position the right block such that it fills the remaining space as the left box expands and contracts in width as the tree expands and collapses.

Is there a way to set the width of the right box based on the current width of the left box?

Basically I have 2 Divs with the following css for those divs...

```
.treeMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: auto;
    margin-right:2px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(218, 235, 245, 6); 
}


.viewer {
    position: relative;
    float:right;

    width: 100%;   
         //100% fills the view port width which is not what I want
         //a fixed width is not what I want either as it will not adjust to the size of the tree menu.
         //if I could set the width or left margin based on the position of the left block's right side I think I could get it to work.

    height: 100%; 
    border: solid;


  }
```

****Thanks to Wesley for the solution to my question****
Working code...

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="treeMenu" >
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="viewer">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font: 100% Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.treeMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: auto;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(218, 235, 245, 6);
}

.viewer {
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    height: 100%; 
    border: solid;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.viewer").append("<img id='theImg' src='Images/FM-000-T01 TITLE INDEX QMC 1824 (1).jpg'/>");
    $('div.viewer').width(($(document).width() - $('div.treeMenu').width())-28);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
       $('div.viewer').width(($(document).width() - $('div.treeMenu').width())-28);
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### pureCSS cross-browser solution: [(demo on dabblet.com)](http://dabblet.com/gist/2787449)

**html:**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="treeMenu">
        <div class="content">menu abc</div>
    </div>
    <div id="viewer">
        <div class="content">menu abc</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#treeMenu, #viewer {
    height: 100%;
}

#treeMenu {
    float: left;
    background: rgba(218, 235, 245);
    padding-right: 3px;
}

#viewer {
    background: red;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Nice. That was what I was trying to do before I asked the question. I couldn't get the background to fill the screen vertically without making treeMenu position:Absolute which messed the other positions up. Is the trick here the #wrap > div. What is that saying? I added the wrap >div to my css set treeMenu back to float:left and removed the float from the viewer. Works like a chanp. Thanks.

Comment: I am very happy to help you, an I updated my solutuion to show scroll when `#viewer` has too much content

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a way to do with you want with just CSS. Maybe it's possible but I doubt there is a clean solution which works cross-browser.

With a little bit of javascript however, it shouldn't be hard.

It's a bit hard to understand what you want exactly, try following code ([jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/QjbyP/)):

html:

```
<div id="treeMenu">menu abc</div>
<div id="viewer">this is the viewer</div>
```

javascript (using jQuery because it's easy):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
       $('#viewer').width($(document).width() - $('#treeMenu').width());
    }).resize();
});
```

css:

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
#treeMenu {
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(218, 235, 245, 6);
    height: 100%;
}
#viewer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. I removed the resize function from around the viewer width setting inside the ready function. Then added a resize function to adjust the width during a window resize. I will add the working code to my question.

Comment: That will work, however you don't need to duplicate the resize logic. The js code I showed above also does the initial resize and the resize on window resize events. (The trick is in the `.resize()` appended to the resize function)

Comment: I put it back the way you had it and, yep, it works just fine. No sure I understand why it works. If you have time, can you explain or point me to an explanation of what the appended .resize() is doing? The ready function is not firing when the window is resizing, so I am assuming that the .resize() binds my resize function to a resize event. Do I got it right? Thanks.